# Is this a Numpy Bug? Numpy ValueError: Object is not aligned

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I tried the following commands:

```
>>> a = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])

>>> a

matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]])

>>> b = np.matrix([[0,1],[0,1]])

>>> b

matrix([[0, 1],
        [0, 1]])

>>> np.dot(a,b)

matrix([[0, 3],
        [0, 7]])
```

So far, everything is fine. But after I made the following changes, suddenly I get an Error:

```
>>> tmp1 = a[np.ix_([1,1,0])]

>>> tmp2 = b[np.ix_([1,1,0])]

>>> tmp1.shape

(3, 2)

>>> tmp2.shape

(3, 2)

>>> np.dot(tmp1,tmp2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

Please help me on what I've ignored when doing the above operations.
I really want to get the dot product of tmp1 .* tmp2 like what I expect from matlab:

matrix([[0, 4], [0, 4],[0, 2]])

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot product of two matrices of size (3,2) is not valid. Try transposing one of them

Comment: but what I really want to get is like this:
matrix([[0, 4],
        [0, 4],
        [0, 2]])
I thought this was the dot product of tmp1 .* tmp2 like what I expect from matlab...

Comment: `np.multiply(tmp1,tmp2)` produces `matrix([[0, 4],[0, 4],[0, 2]])`.  `tmp1.*tmp2` is not the dot product in MATLAB.  It is the element by element product.

Comment: You should ask a new question on how to duplicate ` tmp1 .* tmp2`.  Give us `tmp1` and `tmp2`, not `a` and `b`.

Comment: yeap. I misunderstood the concept. np.multiply(tmp1,tmp2) is what I need.

Comment: http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-13d7391dd7e2c57d293809cff080260b46d8e664 - numpy for matlab users